# What does 是是 mean beyond 是? Is it just a typo?

Tags: meaning, usage, difference

This question relates to the following snippet:

> 不约而同是一个成语，读音**是是**bù yuē ér tóng，意思是指事先没有约定而相互一致。
>   <sub>Baidu Baike，[不约而同](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8D%E7%BA%A6%E8%80%8C%E5%90%8C/1638708)</sub>

It introduces the chengyu (idiom) 不约而同, which means something like "doing something consistently, but without prior arrangement".  I'm just wondering why 是是 is used here---I haven't seen this before, so maybe it just means 是? Or maybe it's a typo?

**Question**: What does 是是 mean beyond 是?  Is it just a typo?

Putting [是是](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%98%AF%E6%98%AF) into YouDao gives this example: 你认为将会是是错误的决策.  Maybe it's more tentative than plain 是, like 看看 perhaps.  I'm not clear on this.

Comment: It's just a typo. 是 could not be used as 是是 like 看 and 看看.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment and the other answer said it's definitely a typo.

Note that in *highly informal* daily conversations, a sequence of "是" or "好" can express impatience,  or can indicate dismissal of other person's opinion (with an arrogant/inpatient/derogatory tone) despite repeatedly answering "yes". I'm not sure if such a pattern is also present in English though.

Example:

> A: 你是不是脑子有问题啊? (Are you a idiot?)
>   B: **是是是是**，你觉得是，那就是，不狡辩。(meaning: I don't give a ** about what you think.)

Answer (score 1):

It is a typo here, but in some dialects 是是 means 是不是, which is another story.

Comment: "in some dialects 是是 means 是不是"? I don't believe it. Give me some proof. I would accept '是不?' can be the shortened form of '是不是' but  '是是' is just  too illogical to be considered as a shortened form of '是不是'

Comment: @Tang Ho  It is logical, it is just 吞音. e.g. "明天要下雨, 是是".

Answer (score -1):

"啊是是是"表示躺平，摆烂。accept whatever you said but did nothing.

Comment: Please read the question before answering.